# How do you stub out User.Identity.Name in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd

I'm trying to unit test a page in my ASP.NET MVC application that, when posted to, will delete a user's item.  I want to restrict this page so that it can only be posted to by the owner of said item.  Originally, I wanted to just stick a quick check in the controller that checked if the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is equal to the owner of the item, but I quickly realized that unit testing this would be difficult.

Should I create an interface that provides a way to access the current logged-in user's name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line of your question is probably the quickest solution, however, I don't think you need to create the interface, `HttpContext.Current.User` is already an `IPrincipal` and `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` is already an `IIdentity`.

If your checking logic uses either of those interfaces, the controller can be mocked to pass an IIdentity that you create instead of the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code

```
Controller CreateControllerAs(string userName) {

  var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
  mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns(userName);
  mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

  var controller = new SomeController();
  controller.ControllerContext = mock.Object;

  return controller;
}
```

It uses [moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/) lib

Comment: Do you know where can I find the Mock class? I've looked all over MSDN trying to find documentation about it but haven't made any progress.

Answer (score 2):

I use Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name. It's trivial to create a GenericPrincipal for a unit test and attach it.